# User haven't permissions for calling showModalDialog()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

In Google Sheets I use this code for opening a URL after a user edits some cell, but there is problem: I can open the URL in a modal window, but other editors cannot. When I review the Stackdriver logs, I see errors that state the script does not have permission to call showModalDialog().

```js
function onEditTrigger(e) {
  var eRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActive().getActiveRange();
  var eRow = eRange.getRow();
  var eCol = eRange.getColumn();

  if (eCol == 1) 
    openUrl("https://stackoverflow.com");
}

function openUrl(url) {
  var html = "<script>window.open('" + url + "'); google.script.host.close();</script>";
  var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setHeight(6).setWidth(9);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(userInterface, 'Opening ...');
}
```

I have installed an "edit" trigger for the "onEditTrigger" function. How can I make sure it works for all editors?

Comment: @tehhowch, No results. I've deleted all triggers and reinstalled them in onInstall(e) but there is no any changes and modal window don't open when other editor of table try to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have your script executing JS code snippets simply by sharing it with other users. Your collaborators will still need to open the Script Editor and **manually** re-authorize the bound script. Sure thing, Google will throw the usual warnings at them while they do it.

The OnEditTrigger will still fire but injecting client-side code will result in failure.

JS code can be used for malicious purposes and stealing private data, so I don't think Google will allow anyone to avoid the explicit authorization flow.